# How to exclude a button in a dynamically generated page from refreshing with other contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please guys i need your ever reliable assistance in fixing this:
I have a page which loads users comments from database with ajax and a setInterval function used to 
refresh the page every 5 seconds. Each comment displays with a dynamically generated reply button underneath 
that fades out to reveal reply textarea field upon clicking.
What i'm trying to achieve is to exclude the button from refreshing alongside the contents every 5 seconds. 
This is because when the reply button is clicked and the reply textarea is revealed for reply to be typed, at 5 
seconds the page refreshes, the textarea closes and the button returns.
Here is my fetch_posts.php file:

```
    <?php
    require ("includes/conn.php");
                $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT post_id, name, topic, post, time FROM posts ORDER BY time DESC");
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
                if ($num_of_rows > 0){
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        $id = $row['post_id'];
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $topic = $row['topic'];
                        $post = $row['post'];
                        $time = strtotime($row['time']);
                        $time = date('d M, H:i a', $time);
            ?>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <img src="images/human_avtr.png" alt="image" width="50px" height="50px" background="#FC6806">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <h5 style="color:#FC6806"><strong><?php echo ucfirst($name); ?></strong></h5><h6 style="color:#FC6806"><?php echo $time; ?></h6>
                        <h5 style="color:#0269C2"><strong><?php echo ucfirst($topic); ?></strong></h5>
                        <p><?php echo $post; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row col-md-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="reply_button">Reply</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row reply_txt" style="clear:both">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1" id="rep_fields">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comment_reply" rows="3"></textarea><br/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="send_reply">Reply Comment</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="cancel_reply">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <?php }
                }
           ?>
<script>
     $(".reply_txt").hide();
</script>
```

And here my jquery to fade out the post reply button, reveal the reply textarea, fetch data and set the SetInterval function.

```
 $(document).on("click", "button#reply_button", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var reply_button = $(this).closest('div');
            var reply_field = reply_button.next(".reply_txt");
            $(reply_button).fadeOut();
            $(reply_field).fadeIn();
        });
function fetchPosts(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch_posts.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            success: function(data){
                $("#show_comments").html(data);
                 fetchPosts();
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(fetchPosts, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend rewriting your code to have fetch_posts.php return a [JSON String](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) of the post information and have the $.ajax success function create the HTML for the posts. This way you're passing less data between the server and client, and you can use Javascript to parse the data by ID and append new posts, rather than overwrite all existing ones. I would even go as far as having the $.ajax request tell fetch_posts.php what the most recent post is and change the MySQL query to only pull newer posts.

**EDIT** to help with getting started coding:

PHP could be rewritten to export a JSON string instead of HTML:

```
<?php
require ("includes/conn.php");
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT post_id, name, topic, post, time FROM posts ORDER BY time DESC");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
if ($num_of_rows > 0){
    $dataArray = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data['post_id'] = $row['post_id'];
        $data['name'] = $row['name'];
        $data['topic'] = $row['topic'];
        $data['post'] = $row['post'];
        $data['time'] = date('d M, H:i a', strtotime($row['time']));
        $dataArray[] = $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($dataArray);
}
?>
```

and have javascript parse it (create the HTML string):

```
$(document).on("click", "button#reply_button", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var reply_button = $(this).closest('div');
    var reply_field = reply_button.next(".reply_txt");
    $(reply_button).fadeOut();
    $(reply_field).fadeIn();
});
function fetchPosts(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "fetch_posts.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            // This will return an object like this:
            // {0: {post_id: '', name: '', ...}, 1: {post_id: '', name: '', ...}}
            // You can then use these objects in your javascript.
            $.each(data, function(post) {
                // FIRST check if the post_id is already in the posts:
                if ( !$("#posts_list").children("div[data-id=" + post.post_id + "]").exists() ) {
                    var thePostHTML = "<div data-id=\"" + post.post_id + "\">"; // etc...
                    $("#posts_list").append(thePostHTML);
                } 
            });
        $("#show_comments").html(data);
        fetchPosts();
        }
    });
}
setInterval(fetchPosts, 5000);
```

Comment: `I would recommend rewriting your code to have fetch_posts.php return a JSON String of the post information and have the $.ajax success function create the HTML for the posts`. @D.R please could you throw more light on this please. Do you have an example you can show me or the link to a resource that can guide me on this?Thanks in anticipation

Comment: thanks so much @ D.R..this would be very helpful. Once i implement it i'd get back to u pls. Sorry for acknowledging this late i've been on trip.Thanks

Comment: Once again thanks @D.R. I implemented the code and made some modifications. But i'm still having challenges with the Reply button. Once the button is clicked, it fades out and the textarea shows up, however, once its the time set at setInterval function, the button refreshes along with the comment, closing the reply textarea and then showing the button all over again. How do i exclude the button and textarea from refreshing with the comments please?This was my challenge from the start.Thanks.

Comment: The trick is to request *new* posts from fetch_posts.php (You can do this by using a $_GET or $_POST variable), and then append (**not** replace) to the posts. This way you're not overwriting the posts every interval.

Comment: thanks @D.R. Exactly the idea on my mind! But how do i implement this please?